# SFTPOperator in Airflow not working with a conn_id

Tags: airflow

I set up an SFTP site using this image:

https://hub.docker.com/r/atmoz/sftp/

I was able to connect to this from the local computer which hosts the SFTP, from the server Airflow is running on (using sftp command), and from a Windows machine with WinSCP.

However, when I create a Connection in the webserver UI with the correct username and password, my dag always has an error saying that the password is incorrect (not possible).

I then tried to remove the password and just generate keys. This worked on all of my machines, but my tasks would fail saying that the key was not a valid OPENSSH key.

extra='{"key_file": "/home/airflow/airflow/.ssh/id_rsa", "no_host_key_check": "true"}'

I am able to connect to the SFTP using pysftp as well. I do need to indicate the CNOTPS = None. I have been using pysftp for the past year or so, but I was hoping to just replace it all with the SFTP operator for the sake of uniformity.